# Get maximum from xts object using merge function

Tags: r, merge, xts, quantmod

Hi I'm using R quantmod library and I would like to find and return the maximum of two values (volume today, vs volume yesterday).

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("HELE")
# Ok now when I do this it does not return a single column with the highest 
# volume 
head(    merge( HELE, max (HELE$HELE.Volume,lag(HELE$HELE.Volume, k=1    )  ) ) )
```

this generally works because for example say I want to subtract today's high from yesterday close I can do this.

```
head(    merge(HELE, abs(HELE$HELE.High - lag(HELE$HELE.Close, k=1)   ) ) )
```

I also tried apply function but did not work as well,

```
head(    merge(HELE, as.xts(apply( c(lag(HELE$HELE.Volume, k=1    ), HELE$HELE.Volume    ), 1, max) )      ) )
```

Thanks in advance. 
Ahdee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
head(merge(HELE, pmax (HELE$HELE.Volume,lag(HELE$HELE.Volume, k=1), na.rm=TRUE)))
```

`pmax` is the vectorised version of `max` i.e. it finds the pairwise `max` between two vectors. You also need to include a `na.rm=TRUE` otherwise you will end up with NAs where you have missing values.

Using only `max` it would find the global max between the two vectors and create a column filled with this value only.

Output:

```
> head(merge( HELE, pmax (HELE$HELE.Volume,lag(HELE$HELE.Volume, k=1 )  , na.rm=T) ) )
           HELE.Open HELE.High HELE.Low HELE.Close HELE.Volume HELE.Adjusted HELE.Volume.1
2007-01-03     24.25     25.16    24.25      25.12      251800         25.12        251800
2007-01-04     25.15     25.50    25.06      25.49      224400         25.49        251800
2007-01-05     25.45     25.50    24.78      24.93      289700         24.93        289700
2007-01-08     24.82     25.19    24.65      24.69      285000         24.69        289700
2007-01-09     21.84     22.60    21.75      22.19     1534800         22.19       1534800
2007-01-10     22.11     22.50    21.87      22.45      293600         22.45       1534800
```

Comment: thanks this works great; I'm still not fully understanding why this does not work though.  It seems like some functions using merge, does not appear to be reading data for that particular row, for example do you know why the first function fails but the last one does not? `head( merge(HELE, mean(c( HELE$HELE.High, HELE$HELE.Low, HELE$HELE.Close     )          ))) ; 

head( merge(HELE,  abs(HELE$HELE.High- HELE$HELE.Low- lag(HELE$HELE.Close,k=2 )    )          ))`

Comment: The first one fails because mean does not do row wise calculations. Mean is not vectorised. For a row wise calculation of the mean you need to use an `apply` type function. `mean(c( HELE$HELE.High, HELE$HELE.Low, HELE$HELE.Close ) )` will find the mean of all those vectors. You don't want that. You want the row wise means so you cant use `mean`. It is the same reason why I used `pmax` instead of `max`. Try `max(c(1,2), c(3,4))` and `pmax(c(1,2), c(3,4))` and you will see the difference. There is no `pmean` function unfortunately so you need to use `apply` with `mean`.

Comment: One the other hand `-` is vectorised so it will work as expected. I can say it in a different way as well: `mean` is not vectorised and thus will reduce the 2 vectors into a single value. `-` is vectorised so will return a new vector that is the same size as the two individual starting vectors. I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes explanation works, thanks again.  Would you by any chance know how to use lag function during an apply? what I want to do is to take an average of the High over a 14 period, but using the apply function does not seem to work for this.

Comment: You are welcome :). That's a good question. I would have to think about it to be honest because `lag` works with `time series` objects. If you still try to find a way to calculate the row wise mean just do it yourself: `head( merge((HELE, HELE$HELE.High + HELE$HELE.Low + HELE$HELE.Close)/3 ))) `. This is the easy way. If you still want to find out how to do it with an `apply`  (if it is possible) I suggest you ask a new question with a reproducible example like this one and people will help. I will be able to help later on as well.

Comment: thanks again.  I finally figured it out by first understanding what I wanted thanks to another post elsewhere; its called a rolling mean. I used a rollapply function, as such, `meanXdays = rollapply(temp, 14, mean, na.pad = 1, align="right")`

Comment: Really glad I could be of help and happy that you found something that works for your problem!!  :)